# Can I use WebRTC to receive a standard RTP video stream?

Tags: javascript, rtp, webrtc

I have two computers on the same network. One of them transmits a movie (H264) with RTP protocol. Is it possible to create a simple javascript app to receive this stream on the second computer and display in a video tag?

So far my impression of WebRTC is that it's designed to be used between browser (both using WebRTC api), but I want to use it only on the receiving side.

Comment: This is a good question, I would like to stream video from my embedded device and I was hoping I could just parse the video with the new JavaScript APIs.

Comment: I know I'm coming late to the party but did you find any solution to your problem? if so, would you mind sharing? @Pal Szasz

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to stream video using WebRTC, you can send only data parts with RTP protocol, on the other side you should use [Media Source API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html) to stream video.

Here is [article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API) with [demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html) explained about Media Source API

Comment: This looks very interesting, but I don't see the whole picture yet. Currently I already have one machine which sends the H264 encoded video using RTP. What I need is a way to receive this stream and display it in the browser. It seems using the MediaSource API I can feed the video tag with the stream, but how I receive the stream?

Comment: You can send data through dataChannel as chunks.

Comment: But how do I receive the RTP/UDP packets?

Comment: anything new on this topic?

Comment: @WooDzu, did u find any solution for your requirement?. if so, would you mind sharing?. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

May be this might help [Janus-Gateway](http://janus.conf.meetecho.com/demos.html).
This has listed RTP in [Dependencies](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway#dependencies)

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial using gstreamer to send RTP to janus and display it using WebRTC http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/eng/blog/building-a-raspberry-pi-2-webrtc-camera?/designspark/electronics/blog/building-a-raspberry-pi-2-webrtc-camera=

Comment: The example does work using the Janus demo page, but it involves installing a web server and has lots of dependencies in the demo page. Is there a simple "install Janus, start gstreamer, open webpage on other computer" example, that involes only 1-3 files (html+js)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

you can use [the mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/communication-between-client-and-server/#producing-media-from-an-external-endpoint) for this it provides apis for receiving and sending RTP.